# Reading environment variables with ad-hoc ansible command

Tags: linux, ansible

I am trying to run a simple ad-hoc ansible command on various hosts to find out if a directory exists.

The following command works correctly by returning `exists` although it does not print the environment variable beforehand:

```
ansible all -i hosts.list -m shell -a "if test -d /the/dir/; then echo '$HOSTNAME exists'; fi"
```

Can anyone please tell me why only `exists` is returned instead of `HOSTNAME exists`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's included in double quotes (`"`), your `$HOSTNAME` is being interpreted by your *local* shell. You probably want to write instead:

```
ansible all -i hosts.list -m shell -a \
  'if test -d /the/dir/; then echo "$HOSTNAME exists"; fi'
```

In most cases you will want to use single quotes (`'`) for your argument to `-a` when you're using the `shell` module to prevent your local shell from expanding variables, etc, that are intended to be expanded on the remote host.